# how I can use sort function in findOne() mongodb function?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

both methods are not working with findOne :

```
await colllections.findOne({}, { sort: { timestamp: -1} })

await colllections.findOne({}).({ sort: { timestamp: -1} })
```

anyone have any idea ?

Comment: Since `findOne()` retrieves, at most, a single document, there is nothing to sort. What are you attempting to do here?

Comment: actually i need get most recent day or last day's  data. so first am finding latest data to get latest date by sorting.

Comment: any other way to get latest or recent days day

Answer (score -1):

In the comments you have clarified that you are attempting to return the most recent document according to the `timestamp` field. You may apply a `limit(1)` to a `.find().sort()` in order to achieve this. It would look something like:

```
await colllections.find({}).sort({ timestamp: -1}).limit(1).toArray()[0]
```

The playground doesn't let you do this directly, but you can see an example of the aggregation equivalent [here in this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EKaL-sr3V3l).

Comment: if we have many data's , this query is very expensive

Comment: Why? If you have an index on `{ timestamp: 1 }` then only a single document will be scanned and returned. Verbose explain output will confirm that. There is nothing different here than if you were to do a `findOne()` with an indexed filter, the exact same efficiency

Comment: no i just tried both with around 1gb data with collection of 4million records,  
findOne return very fast,  but find().limit(1) taking few seconds .

Comment: Please gather the output of `.explain("executionStats")` for the query, save it somewhere (eg a gist in github or pastebin.com), and share the link here

Comment: @shafavp `find().limit(1)` is very different from `find().sort({timestamp:-1}).limit(1)` if there is an index on timestamp